# How to add a RibbonButton to a context menu in Outlook?

Tags: button, outlook, contextmenu, ribbon

I am at a loss how to add a custom button to a context menu in Outlook 2013. In Outlook 2007 and 2010 I manage to do that successfully with a CommandBarButton, but that is not possible anymore in 2013. Unfortunately, I could not find a tutorial how to convert my code or mitigate the issue.

My question now is: How can I create, add and access a custom RibbonButton that should appear in the Outlook context menu of mail, calendar and contact items?

I have already tried simple code like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
  <contextMenus>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMailItem">
      <button id="MyContextMenuContactItem"
           label="ContextMenuContactItem"
           onAction="OnMyButtonClick"/>
    </contextMenu>
  </contextMenus>
</customUI>
```

... but nothing happens, it is not displayed. The constructor of its .cs file is called, but nothing else.

If I try adding it programmatically via

```
Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory().CreateRibbonButton()
```

.. then I do not know how to add it to a preexisting context menu.

I must be missing something that is necessary to add the item to the context menu. Can anyone please point me to it?

PS: I am testing with Outlook 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by a wrong stub that was automatically inserted by Visual Studio. The return value of `GetCustomUI` was always null because `GetResourceText` could not find the resource (although to me it looked valid). When I changed it to `File.ReadAllText(Properties.Resources.MyRibbonXmlFile)`, `Ribbon_Load` was finally called.